# Writing a large portion of text in 'code font'

Tags: fonts

I need to write a large portion of text in 'code font' that includes an `enumerate`. I like the style provided by `texttt`, but it doesn't work in my case.

I would like something like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\begin{document}

\texttt{Report:
\begin{enumerate}
\item First Observation
\item Second Observation
\end{enumerate}
}

\end{document}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You would probably follow the suggestion in [How do I use a particular font for a small section of text in my document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25249/5764) and create an environment (to limit the scope of the font change), or merely use `\begingroup\ttfamily ... \endgroup`.

Comment: Please provide an [MWE (Minimal Working Example)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) starting with `\documentclass{article}`, ending with `\end{document}`. And welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: I'd even try `\begin{ttfamily} ... \end{ttfamily}`.

Answer (score 2):

To typeset text in typewriter font ("code font")  use the `ttfamily` environment:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\begin{document}

\begin{ttfamily}% switch to tt font
 Report:
\begin{enumerate}
  \item First Observation
  \item Second Observation
\end{enumerate}
\end{ttfamily}
% back in normal font
More text in text font.

\end{document}
```

[image]

If, however, your goal is to write *code*, using the `verbatim` environment (or, for syntax highlighting, the `listings` package) will be a better fit.

Comment: `ttfamily` change indeed the font *but* it only does this and cannot handle properly code sample (spaces and line break manager, ...).

Comment: @ppr then please explain to us exactly what it is you want to accomplish, because we do not understand.

Comment: I don't want to accomplish anything (I'm not the one who asked the question). I just indicated that `ttfamily` *isn't* a good way to print code. It just changes the font and printing code is not just about the font...

Comment: @ppr: Your comment about `verbatim` is right, but does not address the OP's question. AFAIU the OP does not want to typeset LaTeX _code_, but wants some piece of text (including an itemize list) to be typeset in a typewriter font.

Comment: @Daniel ok I missed this point.